# Why are my try and except clauses not working?

Tags: python, try-catch, except

```
#I will write a program to spurt out objects of a list
import sys
list=[]


for i in range(0,len(list)-1):
    try:
        print(list[i]+',',end=' ')
    except IndexError:
        sys.exit()

print("and "+list[-1])
```

I tried putting the whole for loop in thw try clause and i still get IndexError im stuck. I had to find a way to deal with empty lists, because the code works with other lists.

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? Exactly what do you think should happen, step by step, when the code runs? Exactly what does happen, and exactly how is that different?

Comment: Think carefully about the logic of the code. Is `print("and "+list[-1])` inside of a `try` block, or outside of any `try` blocks? Will it work for an empty list?

Answer (score 2):

What is the length of your list when the print statement is called? If the list is empty, ANY index into the list is out-of-bounds.

There is also a secondary issue with your print statements. The + operator can be used to concatenate strings, so something like

```
 value = "5"
 print("and " + value)
```

works just fine. However, you can't use + to concatenate a string with a number, so this

```
 value = 5
 print("and " + value)  # this is an error
```

will result in an error. One correct way to do it would be with the comma operator, like so:

```
 value = 5
 print("and", value)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Firstly**, setting a variable's name to `list` is bad practice, as doing this overwrites the default `list()` function in python (in this instance), so let's change the name of the variable in your script from `list` to `var` to minimize any chances of future issues/misunderstandings.

#### A rewrite of your script:

```
from sys import exit

var = []

for i in range(0, len(var) - 1):
    try:
        print(var[i] + ',', end = ' ')
    except IndexError:
        exit()

print("and " + var[-1])
```

Note that you defined `var` as an empty list before we review your for-loop.

Review `len(var) - 1` in `for i in range(0, len(var) - 1)`. As the script is executing, remember that `var` is still an empty list once the interpreter begins reading the line containing the for-loop. The `len()` function counts how many elements are in a string, list, tuple, etc. So, in your for-loop, the iterator `i` begins at `0`, and the nested code following your for-loop is executed *until `i` is greater-than-or-equal-to `-1`*, seeing as `len(var) - 1` is equivalent to `0 - 1`.

In other words, any code that is nested under the for-loop is executed a total of `-1` times -- meaning that any code nested under the for-loop is completely ignored, and the interpreter jumps straight to the `print` function at the end of your script, **which is where the `IndexError` occurs**.

Review `var[-1]` in `print("and " + var[-1])`. A negative index of a list in Python refers to accessing elements in a list by counting ***from the last** element **to the first** element of the list, rather than from the first element to the last*. In other words, `var[-1]` points to whatever element is stored at index `0` **of the reversed list**, or (put more simply) `var[-1]` would point to the last element of the list `var`.

### Summary

> You're attempting to access *the last element* of an empty list, which will always throw an IndexError. The print function at the end of your script is not part of the try block, being why you're still receiving an IndexError.

Cheers.

Answer (score -2):

**Solution**:

I don't think the try / except is necessary but all you really need to do is check the length of your list before trying to print a final element.

```
list=[]

for i in range(0,len(list)-1):
    print(list[i]+',',end=' ')

if len(list)>0:
 print("and "+list[-1])
```

Comment: As far as the try / except blocks I'm not sure if you need to use any of those but you can decide for yourself it They're needed. Maybe there is more to your project that this example.